# Tracking users locations in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, maps, tracking

I would like to track the location of multiple users who use my website through their mobile browsers, in a centralised dashboard.

My environment is ASP.NET Core.
i tried open layers to get user's current coordinates (langitude, latitude).
the idea i am thinking of is to send coordinates to server every second,
storing it at database , then plotting them , is this the right approach

Comment: What exactly is your question? What did you try? Where did you got stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const successCallback = (position) => {
     // Call your API here to save the position (latitude,longitude) of 
     user
};

const errorCallback = (error) => {
  console.log(error);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

You can get your users current location using JavaScript geolocation API and create a mapping of the location and users, then use that data to set up your dashboard.

Comment: thank you i was thinking the same , but i was told that ip address geo is not very acurrate, is it better to use bing maps for getting the coordinates

Comment: It will actually ask the user permission to respond with location from your device. If it's a mobile device the client is browsing the site with you can expect pretty precise location if the user gives appropriate permission. If it's a computer device or doesn't have GPS/appropriate hardware it'll give an approximate location depending on the network. Bing or google maps doesn't have anything to do with it I think.

Comment: okay , so i will send coordinates  to server  when the user changes location . then on server what is the right approach .. i make a task that is executed every second .. check thee coordinates and plot them ?

Comment: You can save it in a database table then when you go to the dashboard, you can plot the data reading the information's from database. There's many JS libraries to do that.